# How to execute the same code when a button is pressed or when a CountDownTimer reaches zero in Android?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I have created a `button` and set an `OnClickListener`. I also added a `CountDownTimer` to my app. When the `button` is pressed or `CountDownTimer` reaches zero (`onFinish`), i want the same thing to happen. So, if the `button` is pressed fist, i want something to be done, if the `button` isn't pressed but the `CountDownTimer` reaches zero, i want the same thing to be done. I want that, without copying the lines from the `OnClickListener`. Where i wrote `// code`, it means that there is a lot of code. How can i do that? Here is my code:

```
finishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // code to be executude

});

public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {

    public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write finishButton.performClick(); inside the onFinish() method

Answer (score 1):

> i want the same thing to be done. I want that, without copying the lines from the OnClickListener

Just move your code to separate method and call that method from any place you need.

Comment: Thank you, but can you be more specific please? Can you write me some code?

Comment: well, i could, but frankly this is so elementary that if you cannot create method yourself then how come you got any code written so far?

Answer (score 0):

You have a same code which is run both in `onFinish` method and `OnClickListener` method. So put your code inside another method(for example `repeatedMethod` and call it in `onFinish` and `OnClickListener`:

```
public class TempClass extends Activity {

private void repeatedMethod() {
    // do some thing
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Button finishButton = new Button(this);
    finishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // code to be executude
            repeatedMethod();
        }
    });
}


class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {

    public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        repeatedMethod();
    }
}
}
```